# what transaction behavior should we expect if the client dies?

Tags: database, postgresql

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE saving SET balance = balance - 100.00 WHERE name = 'Alice';

UPDATE checking SET balance = balance + 100.00 WHERE name = 'Alice';

COMMIT
```

During this transaction, my client dies before commit. what would I expect the DB's state?

Let me use a concrete example from 
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/bmp4.html

The example shown at the end of the page has the logic of either "commit" or "rollback" explicitly. But what would happen if the client process dies right after the operation:

" AuctionItem ai= home.create(seller, description, auctiondays, startprice, summary);"

the client has not got the chance to catch exception to rollback, nor has it chance to do commit.

Comment: If answers help you, you should accept them. It's the cost <ironic> (very expensive...) </ironic> to post question on that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually the tcp keep alive mechanism in the OS will kill the connection.  when it does the database will roll back the transaction, as it's the only possible choice without an explicit commit.  While the connection is alive and idle, you will have a lock on the data and an entry in the pg_stat_activity table indicating "idle in transaction".  Any updates by another connection to the rows your transaction has a lock on will wait for it to commit / rollback.

Default tcp_keepalive timeout is 2 hours and some odd minutes for retries.

Comment: This is the worst possible cenario -- in case the whole client machine loses connection and doesn't come back. In general, however, only the process on the client machine dies and the OS immediately resets the connection.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no auto commit, then the values won't have changed if the DBMS doesn't do a commit

Comment: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/bmp4.html

The example shown at the end of the page has the logic of either "commit" or "rollback" explicitly.

But what would happen if the client process dies right after operation "    AuctionItem ai= home.create(seller, 
 description, 
 auctiondays, 
 startprice, 
 summary);"

Comment: But what happens when another process tries to write to the very same rows as the failed process? Does the second(new) process get an integrity error or is allowed to sail smoothly?